# Using UINavigationController navigationItem -> rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've seen numerous examples where people stick a UIActivityIndicatorView in the customView of a rightBarButtonItem of UINavigationController. While I like this approach I'm a bit concerned about the potential implications.

Will the UINavigationController never make use of this item for forward navigation for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to use a UIActivityIndicatorView or any other UIView as customView of a rightBarButtonItem; rightBarButtonItem is never used for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, **rightBarButtonItem** is a customizable bar button item. The contents of this property always refer to the first bar button item in the 
rightBarButtonItems array.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem;
```

This property is just for the purpose of rendering the right BarButton of UINavigationController. **It is not used by UINavigationController for forward navigation.**